# Ошибка: no such table: dataframe

Tags: python, sql, sqlite

Я получаю исключение `no such table`, хотя до этого таблица было создана

Вот мой код

```
def open_conn():
    __file__ = "C:/.../nn"
    # Получаем текущую директорию
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    
    # Создаем путь до файла базы данных в папке smart_app_db
    db_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'dataframe.db')
    
    try:
        # Создаем подключение к базе данных
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        if conn:
            # Создаем курсор для выполнения запросов
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            return conn, cursor
        return conn, None
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None, None
```

Я вызываю open_conn и могу даже не передавать в него данные, как выводиться исключение`no such table`

```
conn, cursor = open_conn()

sql = f"""
    INSERT INTO dataframe
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
    """
try:
    asd = cursor.onUpgrade(sql, data)
    print(asd.fetchone())
except sqlite3.Error as E:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка, при работе с базой данных: {E}")
finally:
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
```

```
Произошла ошибка, при работе с базой данных: no such table: dataframe
```

Однако, если я прочитаю ее с помочью pandas, то таблица выводится

```
cnx = sqlite3.connect('dataframe.db')

df = pd.read_sql_query("SELECT * FROM dataframe", cnx)
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Подскажите, как я могу исправить это?

Comment: `db_path` точно правильный получается?

Comment: Я же могу создать таблицу. Но почему то, не могу к ней после создания обратится

Comment: Может у вас всё-таки два разных файла с базой, в разных каталогах?

Comment: Я же указываю примой путь к дазе данных "__file__ = "C:/.../nn""

Answer (score 0):

Вы создали базу под одной учетной записью. А пытаетесь ее найти под другой. Посмотрите привилегии пользователей как в самом Windows, так и пользователи SQL.

```
SHOW GRANTS FOR 'username'@'host';
```

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON my_db_cli.* TO 'user_cli'@'%' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

cоздает все привилегии на базу ()

Так же не забывайте про разницу между "localhost" и "%"
Это для внутренних и внешних запросов.

Comment: Не совсем понимаю, что вы имеете введу. И я не знаю разницу про "localhost"и "%"

Comment: Использование "localhost" или "%" зависит от ваших конкретных потребностей в безопасности и функциональности вашей базы данных. Если вам нужно ограничить доступ к MySQL только для локальных соединений, используйте "localhost". Если вам нужно, чтобы MySQL был доступен для удаленных клиентов, используйте "%", но будьте осторожны и следите за безопасностью вашей системы.

Comment: Хорошо. Но я не совсем понимаю, причем тут учетная запись

Comment: Автор использует SQLite, а не MySql.

Comment: Объясню: в SQLite нет DCL, нет привилегий, нет команд GRANT и REVOKE.

Comment: Спасибо, что поправили

Answer (score 0):

Проблема, которую вы видите, связана с тем, что таблица с именем "dataframe" не существует в базе данных, когда вы пытаетесь выполнить операцию INSERT. В вашем коде не видно создания таблицы "dataframe", и поэтому SQLite выдает ошибку "no such table: dataframe".

Чтобы исправить эту проблему, вы должны сначала создать таблицу "dataframe" перед выполнением операции вставки. Вы можете сделать это с помощью оператора CREATE TABLE. Вот как вы можете модифицировать ваш код:

```
import os
import sqlite3
import pandas as pd
import traceback

def open_conn():
    __file__ = "C:/.../nn"
    current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
    db_path = os.path.join(current_dir, 'dataframe.db')
    
    try:
        conn = sqlite3.connect(db_path)
        if conn:
            cursor = conn.cursor()
            return conn, cursor
        return conn, None
    except Exception as e:
        traceback.print_exc()
        return None, None

conn, cursor = open_conn()

# Создаем таблицу "dataframe", если она не существует
create_table_sql = """
    CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS dataframe (
        column1 TEXT,
        column2 TEXT,
        column3 TEXT,
        column4 TEXT,
        column5 TEXT,
        column6 TEXT,
        column7 TEXT,
        column8 TEXT
    )
"""

try:
    cursor.execute(create_table_sql)
    conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as E:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка при создании таблицы: {E}")

# Теперь можно выполнить операцию вставки
data = (value1, value2, value3, value4, value5, value6, value7, value8)  # Замените значениями, которые вы хотите вставить

insert_sql = """
    INSERT INTO dataframe
    VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)
"""

try:
    cursor.execute(insert_sql, data)
    conn.commit()
except sqlite3.Error as E:
    print(f"Произошла ошибка при работе с базой данных: {E}")
finally:
    conn.close()
```

Здесь мы добавили создание таблицы "dataframe" с использованием оператора CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS перед выполнением операции вставки данных. Это обеспечит существование таблицы в базе данных перед ее использованием.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Почему публикация ответов созданных GPT и ChatGPT недопустима?](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/gpt-policy)

Answer (score 0):

```
__file__ = "C:/.../nn"
# Получаем текущую директорию
current_dir = os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__))
```

Это строчку можно удалить, если вам нужно укать путь от одного файла к проекту, то лучше указывать не примой путь, а путь на одну директорию ниже.